# Android set margin in for cycle

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, margins

I'm trying to put some TextView programmatically in my activity. The problem is that I cannot set their margins (top margin), so that there is some space between them.

The XML layout structure is the following:

```
<ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout_1>

        <RelativeLayout_2>

            <TextView/>

            <EditText/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I omitted all the unnecessary information.

Then in my Activity I do

```
    mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.handicap_layout);
    relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.handicap_layout);

    TextView[] texts = new TextView[6];

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
        texts[i] = new TextView(MyActivity.this);
        texts[i].setText("Text " + (i+1));
        texts[i].setTextSize(20);
        relativeParams.setMargins(0, 10+(10*i), 0, 0);   /* trying to increase the margin */
        texts[i].setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
        mLayout.addView(texts[i]);
    }
```

where mLayout refers to RelativeLayout_1 and handicap_layout to RelativeLayout_2.

The problem is that the margins do not increase and the TextView are showed one above the other.

Has anyone a solution? Thank you!

## EDIT: SOLVED

Ok, I managed to solve the problem: the LayoutParams have to be declared **inside** the for cycle.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take one textview xml file. In that take margins. Once that is done inflate that textview.

```
TextView itemview = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.equipment_item, null);
```

once that is done set your text to that layout.

I think you alredy find the relative layout right. Then add that itemview to relative layout like below.

```
equipmentdetails_layout.addView(itemview);
```

Then you can get the margins.